# Draw elements with Core Graphics or provide images ?

Tags: ios, resources, core-graphics

I am not quite sure whether it is beneficial to draw the visual elements of my app with Core Graphics instead of providing the images. In terms of memory preservation and runtime speed which way is better ?

Comment: I how can we say that without actually profiling and knowing how complex the core graphics drawing should be ? Update with details.

Comment: This question has already been answered many times here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247141/core-graphics-vs-images-for-a-custom-button

Comment: well thank you I looked for a similar question, but could not find any. In fact the answers in the given link are perfect. However, I am still not sure whether to use images or not. From what I have read, CG seems to be faster when you use simple drawing operations for the GPU (not many changing pixels etc). However one answer stated that imageNamed caches the image and this is naturally kind of better for me. So, I am still not sure how to move on ...

Comment: thats wat i said , for a specific case without profiling you can never be a 100 % sure . But i doubt it would make much of a difference . Do whatever is easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In terms of memory preservation and runtime speed which way is better?

`+UIImage:imageNamed:` is most efficient. It caches images, i.e. only one copy of an image is in memory and the image is decoded (from its PNG, JPEG, TIFF, etc. data) when it is needed and kept around for future reuse. If you are worried about memory use, iOS will purge the `UIImage` cache if you are running low or go into the background.

Using Core Graphics to draw an image does not do any caching for you, unless you write the code to draw your image into a context, save the context as a bitmap, cache the bitmap and then reuse it later on. So you end up drawing the same thing over and over every time it is needed. For example, if you override UIView's `-drawRect:` to draw imagery, then during animations it will be called for every single frame (60 times a second). This needlessly burns CPU cycles and battery life.

Bottom line is it depends on what your app is and does.

Comment: Thanks Julius, I will go with the images, simply because of performance reasons. I don't think caching contexts would be that hard of a task, but still, using images just seems to be the right approach I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need your images to Change or animate much ,then you shoud directly use an image.Dont worry so much about performace unless you have like 100 images in a single view controller.

If iPhone can handle games like need for speed , to run an app with various images is an easy task.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Well there are things to both approaches I would like to retain. On the one hand CG might be faster, more customisable and cross platform independent, while images are usually easier to create and are cached internally by the application.